# Hibernate callback before first persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**edit:** I misinterpreted the hibernate documentation, `@PrePersist` does exactly what I wanted. Stackoverflow won't let me delete the question so I'll leave it here for other's amusement.

---

Is there a callback in Hibernate before an Entity is persisted for the first time? I have some computations that should be done on the entity before it is saved for the first time but should not be repeated once the entity has been written to the DB once.

I am looking for something like `@PrePersist` but that gets called only before the first persist.

Comment: why is it not an option to make your computation before `session.persist(object)`call?

Comment: In this case I need to compute an ID for the entity that is per-user and the id should not change once the object has been created

Comment: maybe Interceptor can help you. see my answer.

Comment: I am confused.  `@PrePersist` is going to be called only once when an entity is persisted.  In Hibernate, if you are persisting same entity multiple times, the latter tries will not be successful because the entity is already persisted before, hence there will not be any cases of `@PrePersist` called more than once for an entity

Comment: @AdrianShum I see now, I completely misinterpreted the Hibernate documentation. You are right, `@PrePersist` does exactly what I want

Comment: It is good to leave it as you may not be the only one that is confused by the documentation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@PrePersist` is going to be called only once when an entity is persisted. In Hibernate, if you are persisting same entity multiple times, the latter tries will not be successful because the entity is already persisted before, hence there will not be any cases of `@PrePersist` called more than once for an entity

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your `@PrePersist` call you can perform the action only once. You need a flag that will tell you if the action was not performed already.

Comment: That's doable of course but would prefer it if there was a cleaner way without requiring an additional flag

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement your computation inside of `@PrePersist` annotated method, you can try to set [Entity Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html) if you open new hibernate session:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(new MyBeforePersistInterceptor());
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly then this is just a different interface for the `PrePersist` callback, correct? The problem ist not the interface but that I want different semantics than `@PrePersist` provides.

Comment: @Robin maybe you should explain precisely what you want to have :)